# How do I put my firebase database inside the fragment textview

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm just a newbie programmer here. I am trying to put the value of realtime database to textview txtwatts which is in fragment but the app shows nothing on text and keep crashing.

this is what shows on logcat

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

and when I click the blue text it puts me to this line of code `watts.setText(status);`

this is the code on my main activity what im trying to do is passing the data from firebase to the fragment textview id txtWatts.

```
        watts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtWatts);
        dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        dref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                status = dataSnapshot.child("watts").getValue().toString();
                watts.setText(status);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

activity_main photo:
[image]

and when I try to add this code above it works but it only shows the fragment not including the main activity. `setContentView(R.layout.monitor_fragment);`
it looks like this.

monitor_fragment photo:
[image]

Would be very happy if someone has a solution for this. thank you in advance :)

Comment: How and where is `watts` defined?

Comment: I was about to pass the value from database (firebase) on main activity to the textview txtWatts inside the monitor_fragment.

i defined it as `TextView watts;`

here is the whole code on main activity (https://pastebin.com/uGYMEJMm) not sure if this is allowed I'm new here.

Comment: Have you tried to replace `watts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtWatts);` with `watts = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testt)`, does it work this way?

Comment: I have tried that yesterday and it works but when i try it on txtWatts the app is crashing. I want it to put on txtWatts textview on fragment and btw I also read a question something similar to this and they said "there was no view found for the id that you passed into `findViewById()`"

Comment: Are you sure you have in your layout a TextView with an id txtWatts? I'm afraid you don't, right?

Comment: I have TextView with an id txtWatts in my Monitor Fragment but not in my main activity. btw it is working now I`ve transfer the code from main activity to the fragment which has an id txtWatts and change it to like this https://pastebin.com/19G63sHn.